# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first 1

Tags: c#

i am making a 
[WebMethod].. i want to add a new row in it....in which i want the credit and debit sum...?

```
public DataSet getleger(string accno, string fromdate, string todate)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=123-PC;Initial Catalog=bcounts;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=Saba;Password=123");

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Convert(nvarchar(10),gt.Value_Date,111) as [Value_Date],gt.Voucher_no+'-'+gr.VchrType as voucher,gt.Acct_Nirration,gr.InstrumentNo,gt.Dr_Amount,gt.Cr_Amount  from gl_transaction gt, Gl_Ref gr where gt.Accountno = '" + accno + "'  and gt.Voucher_No=gr.Voucher_no  and gt.Value_Date between '" + fromdate + "' and '" + todate + "'", con);
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet("Ledger");

    adp.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();



}
```

Comment: You might want to read up on SQL Injection e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: Error message isn't clear? And you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: i want to add manually row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't write it like this. Your inline vars are a source for SQL injection. You should really do something like this.

I would also move your connection string out of your methods. No need to keep re-declaring it.

```
private SqlConnection con { get; set; }

public void SetConnection(string server, string database, string username, string password)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(String.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Persist Security Info=True;User ID={2};Password={3}", server, database, username, password));
}

public DataSet getleger(string accno, string fromdate, string todate)
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select Convert(nvarchar(10),gt.Value_Date,111) as [Value_Date],gt.Voucher_no+'-'+gr.VchrType as voucher,gt.Acct_Nirration,gr.InstrumentNo,gt.Dr_Amount,gt.Cr_Amount  from gl_transaction gt, Gl_Ref gr where gt.Accountno = @accno and gt.Voucher_No=gr.Voucher_no  and gt.Value_Date between @fromdate and @todate";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accno", accno);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromdate", fromdate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@todate", todate);

            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                {
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    return ds;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException se)
    {
        //handle error
    }
}
```

Adding a row into your DataSet

```
DataRow row = ds.Tables["TableName"].NewRow();
row["Column1"] = "Stuff";
row["Column2"] = "More Stuff";
ds.Tables["TableName"].Rows.Add(row);
```

If you are looking to sum up columns from your query you should do this in the sql query.

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Comment: i want to add a row manually in it which reads credit amount from db how it can b possible?

Comment: added how to add a row to the dataset

Comment: @sabaawan: tsukasa has done a huge amount of work for you. Proper object lifetime management, avoiding SQL injection attacks, etc. Now you need to get the connection string out of your code like this.

Comment: @sabaawan credit and debit sum, you want to sum up the columns and add it to the DataSet? You should do this in the SQL query, then there is no need to manipulate the DataSet.

Comment: but i want that sum in a row not in the column???

Comment: @sabaawan so you are looking for example. Row 1, the sum of column 1, 2, 3 ...etc in a new column of that row? Can you edit your question with an example layout so I know exactly what you want.

Comment: i want a row in whcih i can add sum of debit and credit???